# How do I make a copy an existing sheet in a spreadsheet then rename the new copy using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, duplicates, copy

I've been trying to find out how to copy a specific sheet in an excel file. So far I haven't found the correct method using Pandas.

All I can find is how to copy the sheet from one file to another.

My goal is to make a copy of "Sheet1" and call it "Sheet2". So the result would be an excel file with sheets "Sheet1" and "Sheet2". "Sheet2" being an exact copy of "Sheet1".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you use pandas for this? Just use openpyxl or xlsxwriter or xlwings directly.

Answer (score 4):

With [openpyxl](/questions/tagged/openpyxl), you can [`copy_worksheet`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.workbook.workbook.html?highlight=copy_worksheet#openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook.copy_worksheet) to make a *dupe* :

```
#pip install openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_worbook

wb = load_workbook("file.xlsx")

dup_ws = wb.copy_worksheet(wb["Sheet1"])
dup_ws.title = "Sheet2"

wb.save("file.xlsx")
```

Output :

[image]

[image]

Comment: **NB:** I don't think you can do this with pandas.

Answer (score 1):

`#whit openpyxl do it:

```
>>>import openpyxl as xl
>>>filename="C:/user/file.xlsx"
>>>wb = xl.load_workbook(filename)
>>>dup_ws = wb.copy_worksheet(wb["Sheet1"])
>>>dup_ws.title = "Sheet2"
>>>wb.save(str(file name))
```

#you also n copy of exist sheet with loop:

```
    >>>import openpyxl as xl 
    >>>filename = "C:/Users/file.xlsx"
    >>>wb = xl.load_workbook(filename)
    >>>for i in range(1,n):
    >>>>dup_ws = wb.copy_worksheet(wb['sheet1'])
    >>>>dup_ws.title = 'i'

`>>>wb.save(str(filename))
```

Comment: Requires a bit more formatting